# Global variable through classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to call a method of a class using a global variable, but there seems to be something wrong with my logic.

In the code below, `A` calls `B` which calls `C` which calls a method of `B`.

```
x = None

class A():

    def __init__(self):

        global x
        x = B()

class B():

    def __init__(self):

        C()

    def bla(self):

        print('bla')

class C():

    def __init__(self):

        global x
        x.bla()

A()
```

The error I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bla'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `x = B()`, the result of calling `B()` cannot be assigned to `x` until *after* `B` is finished initialized.  But `B.__init__()` is called when you create the B instance, and it immediately calls `C()`.  In other words, when you do `x = B()`, things happen in this order:

1. call `B.__init__()`
2. call `C.__init__()` (because of `C()` call in `B.__init__()`)
3. assign result of `B()` to `x`.

But step 3 never happens, because `C.__init__()` raises an error, because step 3 hasn't happened yet so the object hasn't been assigned to `x` yet.

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here, so it's hard to say how best to change your code.  There is no way for `C.__init__` to make use of a variable that will not be defined until after `C.__init__` finishes running.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I understand what's happening now. Can you suggest a way to call the bla method from the B class? I only tried using a global variable because I belived it would work. Technically all I need is to call this B method going from A to B to C then back to the B method.

Comment: @VictorJosé: When do you need/want to call `bla`? It's easy to call it: just remove the call to `C()` from `B.__init__`, then do `x = B()`, and then when that is done do `x.bla()`. The purpose of `C` in your example in unclear, because `C` doesn't do anything except call `x.bla`.  Why don't you just call `self.bla()` directly from `B.__init__`?  You should edit your question to explain what C is doing and what the relationship is between it and B.  For instance, you may want to make C accept an argument, and then call `C(self)`, so that `C` can call `bla` on the `B` instance being initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  your problem

you say
    x = b()
well, x is None until b finishes initializing... which also means until c finishes initializing, which would cause a problem in class C when you do

```
x.bla()
```

Comment: BrenBarn explains it better, please refer to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because x is not completely initialized until it finishes calling the init function for each class. Here you tried to access global x, before completing its initialization.